# How do I see the XML of my DOCX document?

Tags: xml, docx

I want to see my `.docx` in its pure *XML* format.

Various application like internet browsers and visual studio will open the file up in Word for me.

I've also tried renaming the document to `.xml` extension and it just opens up in notepad showing a bunch of unintelligible text.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It's a zipped file. Rename it ending in `.zip` to view it.

Comment: ...then look at the `word/document.xml` file beneath it.

Comment: when I upzip it, then modify document.xml, then zip folder and change to docx it does not open in Word. Say it is corrupted. How can I save modification in DOCX file?

Comment: no need to rename. winrar and 7z can recognize the archive, just right click and select extract

Comment: My mind is blown.  How did I not know this...

Comment: On MacOS (High Sierra) the default archive app seemed to have issues with unpacking the file. Using The Unarchiver (https://theunarchiver.com/) helped, and I didn't need to change the file extension or type.

Comment: @RenatGatin That deserves to be its own question, not a comment. But you have to use OpenXML & open a `WordprocessingDocument`, use a `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()) { string docText = sr.ReadToEnd(); }` That gets the XML to load into a string, then use a `XMLDocument` & modify the `XMLNodes` that you can grab/remove/modify values of/insert new ones, etc. `xmlDoc.LoadXml(docText); XmlNodeList nodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("w:body"); XmlNode bodyNode = nodes[0]; XmlNode firstParagraph = bodyNode.ChildNodes[2];`. Write `docText = xml.OuterXml;`

Comment: Then you need a `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create))) { sw.Write(docText); }` to write your changes back out.

Comment: This talks all about it...https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part

Comment: @RenatGatin you must select all items in the folder and zip, not zip the folder itself. The `[Content_Types].xml` must be at the root of the zip file

Answer (score 24):

Working on macOS, and don't want to install any software to see the XML from your `.docx` documents? Just open up the terminal and:

```
cd path/to/your/file.docx
unzip file.docx -d file-content
```

As mentioned above, `.docx` files are "disguised" zip files, and `unzip` is installed by default on macOS. After using it, your `file-content` folder will contain the various `.xml` files composing the Word document.

Comment: Renaming to .zip didn't work for me on mac without new software. This command method did work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I unpacked the zip file en edited the document.xml using Notepad++ (Plugins/XML tools/Check XML syntax now). Notepad++ noticed me at swapped elements, I placed the elements in a more logical order and repeated the steps until no more issues were found. Then I copied all the files directly into zip using Total Commander and finally renamed it back to *.docx. Word happily opened the file.

What I am saying is that if Word still refuses to open the file then there may be some more issues in one or more of xml files. 
Tip: use IE to quickly check an XML-file. If you see only flat text or even nothing at all, you can bet there is something wrong with the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Just learned today that you can get at the raw XML from foo.docx from the cygwin ( linux-like ) commandline

```
unzip  -q -c 'foo.docx' word/document.xml
```