# Word is compressing images even though "Do not compress images in file" is selected - why?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document in Word 2013 and I've inserted some very high-resolution JPG images (line drawings). When I print to PDF, they look fine. However, as soon as I save the file and reopen it, the drawings are very obviously down-sampled -- the line drawings look choppy and dashed.

As noted in the question, **Do not compress images in file** is selected. I've also set the default output to 220dpi, but that shouldn't matter because I've asked it not to compress. (In any case, 220dpi is not good enough for me - I need this to be a high-quality print.)

I've verified & re-verified the settings, tried many convolutions, and reinserted the original pictures more times than I can count.

What could be causing this to happen? Is there some other option I am missing?

Comment: Have you try to save, open and export to PDF and check what is the quality? Its possible Word just display low quality images to speedup the page rendering on the screen.

Comment: Yup. No, it's not a screen display speed optimization - the pictures are really down-sampled. I can print a file to PDF - get high quality, then save, reopen and print again & it comes out lousy.

Comment: Have you tried [looking into the XML structure](https://superuser.com/questions/278260/how-do-i-see-the-xml-of-my-docx-document) of the `DOCX` before and after saving? (BTW, JPEGs are not meant for line drawings, you'd probably be better off saving in another format like PNG or TIFF)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, too, right. I use quite a number of visio diagrams in my documentation sets and have found that PNGs give me the best results for their size. Especially if there's any need to re-size an image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but fixed it following the following steps:

1. Click to save your Word document
2. Choose "PDF" as the type
3. On the bottom left side—left of the box "Options"—select the option *Optimise for: Standard (publishing online and printing)* instead of *Minimum size (publishing online)*.
4. Save the PDF